# Polymer 1.0 Iron-Ajax

Tags: ajax, polymer

I am trying to get data via a php script that works in Polymer 0.5. 
I just get null response and no errors in Polymer 1.0, below is the code. 
I have tried modifying the PHP to echo anything but I get no response. 
hresponse does fire but at that point only the request information is in ajax the response information is null.
I cannot find an example to see where I have gone wrong.
Thanks

```
<iron-ajax
        id="ajax"
        url=""
        params=""
        handle-as="json"
        on-response="hresponse"
        debounce-duration="300">
</iron-ajax>

and the script

setajax:  function(){
   this.$.ajax.url = "Scripts/getnotes.php";
   this.$.ajax.params='{"SN":"VBA056"}';
   this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
}

hresponse: function(e) {
      console.log(e.detail.response);
      console.log(this.$.ajax.lastResponse);
}
```

Answer (score 25):

When you add the `this.$.ajax.params=` inside the script, it should be an object. When you look into the place inside iron-ajax.html where the request is generated, you will see why this is the case. You are currently adding it as a String. Try to set the line to `this.$.ajax.params={"SN":"VBA056"}` and it should work.

The following example works (assuming you are importing all the required elements):

```
<body>
<my-app></my-app>
<dom-module id="my-app">
<style>
</style>
<template>

  <iron-ajax
      id="ajax"
      url=""
      handle-as="json"
      on-response="hresponse"
      debounce-duration="300">
  </iron-ajax>

  <button on-click="setajax">Click me</button>

</template>
<script>
Polymer({
  is: "my-app",
  setajax: function () {
    this.$.ajax.url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    this.$.ajax.params = {"userId":"1"};
    this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
  },
  hresponse: function(request) {
    console.log(request.detail.response);
    console.log(this.$.ajax.lastResponse);
  }
});
</script>
</dom-module>
</body>
```

Comment: That's it thank you, it has changed since version 0.5, I didn't notice the parameters had changed. Now working thanks again

Answer (score 0):

My 1st time answering and a newbie to programming, so it is not perfectly correct. But it can help you

There is no property as `on-response` as per documentation provided in `https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax`

Your `iron-ajax` has to be modified, i too am a newbie, so i wonder if it works, but worth a try.

```
<iron-ajax
        auto
        url=""
        params=""
        handleAs="json"
        lastResponse="hresponse"
        method='GET'>
</iron-ajax>
```

Also i wonder if your scripts work like that.

Comment: Polymer element properties are automatically changed from camelCase to hyphenated-lower-case attributes (as of v1.0.0).

Comment: "hresponse" should come as "{{ hresponse }}" to  enable binding

Comment: `iron-ajax` has an on-response attribute and so it's valid. `lastResponse` is readonly and takes in a string not a function. Whatever string you give it will be the one you use when calling your data in the template. So if you do `lastResponse: item`, you can now call {{item}} in your markup to access the data--assuming your ajax response is of the correct type and doesn't need to be parsed.